# Emacs and jupyter, using emacs-jupyter mode and org file

Tags: python, emacs, jupyter-notebook

Here's the process I am using now, and wonder if there's an obviously better way using `emacs-jupyter` package  (https://github.com/nnicandro/emacs-jupyter)

I have an org file,
after modifying the org file, I export it using `ox-ipynb`.
Then I can hit run in the jupyter browser.

Then, I can play around with jupyter-repl which I created using `M-x jupyter-server-list-kernels`
The repl has all the variables defined which I setup in the org file.

Is this intended use of this library?

Is there a way for me to directly play around inside the org file without exporting it to ipynb?